# Handling component while screen size and font size have been increased in Jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am designing a card in jetpack compose. I was increasing the font size and display size in samsung device and found that as the size increases the design is breaking.

Normal font and display size:
[image: Normal Font]

Large font and display size:
[image: Large Font]

So in the larger screen how can I can handle it gracefully?

Let's say I want XYZ X ABX to be in three single line while the size increases.

Or let's say the date should be stacked below the XYZ x ABC. What are the possible solutions? I saw flow layout in jetpack compose which is in beta. Is there any other options?

```
 @Composable
fun item(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundImageUrl: String,
    backgroundPlaceholder: Painter,
    backgroundFallbackImage: Painter = backgroundPlaceholder,
    backgroundErrorImage: Painter = backgroundPlaceholder,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    val gradientColors = listOf(
        Color(255, 255, 255, 0),
        Color(0, 0, 0, 153)
    )
    val itembg = Brush.verticalGradient(gradientColors)


    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {}
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .clickable { onClick() },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .data(backgroundImageUrl)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            filterQuality = FilterQuality.High,
            placeholder = backgroundFallbackImage,
            fallback = backgroundFallbackImage,
            error = backgroundErrorImage
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(brush = tripBackground)
                .matchParentSize()
        )

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 84.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(2f),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "XYZ",
                    style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp),
                )

                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_close),
                    contentDescription = null,
                )

                Text(
                    text = "ABC",
                    style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp),
                )
            }

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                text = "13 Nov 2023",
                style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.End
            )
        }
    }
}
```